# How to iterate in Java and return an array

Tags: java

I'm a JavaScript developer but now I have to do something in Java.

I have an object that I get from my database that looks like below and I would like to map through it to return an ArrayList of strings for a particular key.

In JavaScript it would look like this:

```
a = [{age: 26, names: {fname: "Mary", lname: "Jane"}}, {age: 34, names: {fname: "Joe", lname: "Doe"}}];
a.map(b => (b.names.fname));
["Mary", "Joe"] //result
```

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: [This](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-convert-list-to-map/) should help but it's important that the names be unique.

Comment: Have you written any code? Even the classes to represent the data or created `a`? Once you have created `a` it's actually not that different if you use streams e.g.`a.stream().map(x->x.get("names").get("fname")).collect(toList())`

Comment: It's a lot more complicated in actual Java, but here's **one** solution: `System.out.println(new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js").eval("a = [{age: 26, names: {fname: \"Mary\", lname: \"Jane\"}}, {age: 34, names: {fname: \"Joe\", lname: \"Doe\"}}]; a.map(b => (b.names.fname));"));`

Answer (score 0):

Store the Object from the database in a **List** then iterate through the List.

```java
List<Map<String,Object>> = a; //a is the list of objects from database
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(Map<String,Object> mp : a){
    result.add(mp.get("name").get("fname"));
}
```